# python does not iterate correctly over a list

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I try to iterate about a list with 1401 elements. If I use

```py
for ele in range(0,201):
    zws = l1.pop(ele)
    zws = Decimal(zws)
    lx.append(zws)
```

my list has 201 elements left, but it took every second value. But I need the first 201 elements.

[image]

It should have values in 0.01 steps and not 0.02.

This is the entire code:

```py
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

lGesamt = []
lx = []
ly = []

def readCsv():
    with open("MmM01.csv") as metaData:
        csv_reader_object = csv.reader(metaData)
        for row in csv_reader_object:
            lGesamt.append(row)


readCsv()

def axisL():
    axy = lGesamt.pop(0)
    axy = axy.pop(0)
    l1 = []
    l1 = axy.split("  ")
    l1.remove("")
    # 1401 Elements left
    
    for ele in range(0,201):
        zws = l1.pop(ele)
        zws = Decimal(zws)
        lx.append(zws)
    
    
axisL()
print(lx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ele.pop(idx)` pops (i.e. get and remove) the element at index `idx`. Your code is getting the first element (index 0), then the 3rd element (index 1 after removing the previous value), then the 5th element (index 2 after removing the prior 2 values), and so on.

Just do `ele[:201]`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Never thought about pop is removing the elements.